# Group policy results failing with "Invalid class" error

Tags: windows, wmi, group-policy

When trying to run the Group Policy Results Wizard against a specific workstation, I'm getting the following error:

```
The wizard was unable to generate the computer or user's data due to insufficient permissions.

    Details:
    Invalid class
```

I'm guessing that the class being referred to is a WMI class, but I haven't gotten much farther. I've run `sfc /scannow` on the machine with no luck. I've also followed all of the recommendations in this article: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm.

I cannot find anything useful in the event logs and I can't think of anywhere else I could look to find out what's really happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you run "wmic os" elevated on the problem device, do you get invalid class or a permissions problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a script at http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/113-rebuild-wmi to rebuild the WMI repository. RSOP is working now.